# Android Bluetooth LE not managing 2 simultaneous connections with RN4020

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a problem trying to connect with 2 Bluetooth LE modules (RN4020) throught native Android Bluetooth LE API and based on the Bluetooth Gatt sample of Android developers (https://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html). I modified BluetoothLeService.java to hold many connections instead of only one.

This is my process:

1- Start a new service which handle connections

2- Loop to connect devices:

```
for(String address: addresses) {
    mBluetoothLeService.connect(address)
}
```

3- Find characteristics I need

4- Send data:

```
mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(address, mCharacteristic, dataArray);
```

The thing is that when I send data to the first module, it receive it  perfect (onCharacteristicWrite() in BluetoothGattCallback() is called), then I send data to the second module and everything OK! But when I try to send data to the first module again, it doesn't receive it (tested in the board and also onCharacteristicWrite() is not called).

I also try with Reliable Write:

```
btGatt.beginReliableWrite();
characteristic.setValue(bytearray);
btGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
btGatt.executeReliableWrite();
```

but the same problem. The callback:

```
onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status)
```

Status code is 6 (BluetoothGatt.GATT_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED)

I checked connection status to both modules and there were connected every time (no disconnection problem).

Here is the modified class BluetoothLeService.java:

```
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
//    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private Map<String,BluetoothGatt> mBluetoothGatts = new HashMap<>();
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";
    public final static String EXTRA_ADDRESS =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_ADDRESS";

    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);

    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server. address: " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        gatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {

            Log.i(TAG, "--onServicesDiscovered. status: " + status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

            Log.i(TAG, "--onCharacteristicWrite: value: " + Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));


        }

        @Override
        public void onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onReliableWriteCompleted(gatt, status);

            Log.i(TAG, "--onReliableWriteCompleted: status: " + status);
        }



        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(gatt.getDevice().getAddress(), ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };

    private void broadcastUpdate(String address, final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String address, final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);

        // This is special handling for the Heart Rate Measurement profile.  Data parsing is
        // carried out as per profile specifications:
        // http://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/characteristics/Pages/CharacteristicViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.characteristic.heart_rate_measurement.xml
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;
            if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            } else {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            }
            final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
        } else {
            // For all other profiles, writes the data formatted in HEX.
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for (byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // After using a given device, you should make sure that BluetoothGatt.close() is called
        // such that resources are cleaned up properly.  In this particular example, close() is
        // invoked when the UI is disconnected from the Service.

        disconnectAll();
        closeAll();

        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    /**
     * Initializes a reference to the local Bluetooth adapter.
     *
     * @return Return true if the initialization is successful.
     */
    public boolean initialize() {
        // For API level 18 and above, get a reference to BluetoothAdapter through
        // BluetoothManager.
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Connects to the GATT server hosted on the Bluetooth LE device.
     *
     * @param address The device address of the destination device.
     * @return Return true if the connection is initiated successfully. The connection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        // Previously connected device.  Try to reconnect.
        if ( btGatt != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "---Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (btGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "---Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }

        // We want to directly connect to the device, so we are setting the autoConnect
        // parameter to false.
        BluetoothGatt newBtGatt = device.connectGatt(this, true, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "---Trying to create a new connection. address: " + address);

        mBluetoothGatts.put(address, newBtGatt);

        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Disconnects an existing connection or cancel a pending connection. The disconnection result
     * is reported asynchronously through the
     * {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, int, int)}
     * callback.
     */
    public void disconnect(String address) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || btGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "disconnecting gatt");
        btGatt.disconnect();
    }

    public void disconnectAll() {

        // Connecting all devices
        Iterator it = mBluetoothGatts.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String address = (String) pair.getKey();

            disconnect(address);
        }
    }

    public int getConnectionState() {
        return mConnectionState;
    }

    /**
     * After using a given BLE device, the app must call this method to ensure resources are
     * released properly.
     */
    public void close(String address, boolean removeFromMap) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);
        if (btGatt == null) {
            return;
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "closing gatt");
        btGatt.close();

        if (removeFromMap) {
            mBluetoothGatts.remove(address);
        }
    }

    public void closeAll() {

        // Connecting all devices
        Iterator it = mBluetoothGatts.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String address = (String) pair.getKey();

            close(address, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Request a read on a given {@code BluetoothGattCharacteristic}. The read result is reported
     * asynchronously through the {@code BluetoothGattCallback#onCharacteristicRead(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic, int)}
     * callback.
     *
     * @param characteristic The characteristic to read from.
     */
    public void readCharacteristic(String address, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || btGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        btGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }

    public void writeCharacteristic(String address, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                    byte[] bytearray) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || btGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }

        if (characteristic == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Characteristic == null");
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "--> Writing characacteristic: " + Arrays.toString(bytearray) + ", device address: " + address);

//        btGatt.beginReliableWrite();

        characteristic.setValue(bytearray);

//        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
//                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
//        Log.i(TAG, "--connection state: " + bluetoothManager.getConnectionState(btGatt.getDevice(), BluetoothGatt.GATT_SERVER));

        btGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

//        btGatt.executeReliableWrite();

    }

    /**
     * Enables or disables notification on a give characteristic.
     *
     * @param characteristic Characteristic to act on.
     * @param enabled        If true, enable notification.  False otherwise.
     */
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(String address, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                              boolean enabled) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || btGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        btGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

        // This is specific to Heart Rate Measurement.
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            btGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of supported GATT services on the connected device. This should be
     * invoked only after {@code BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()} completes successfully.
     *
     * @return A {@code List} of supported services.
     */
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices(String address) {

        BluetoothGatt btGatt = mBluetoothGatts.get(address);

        if (btGatt == null) return null;

        return btGatt.getServices();
    }
}
```

Any ideas or libraries to handle multiple BLE connections? Thanks!

Comment: Try restricting yourself to only  having one call in progress to one device at a time.  The Api should not be like this but it's the only way I have got any reliability.  The initial connection can be a real pain like this.  If you get into a bad state turning BT on and off sometimes fixes things sometimes a power cycle is needed.  The stack is very buggy search the issues tracker.

Comment: Thanks @Ifor . I finally found a solution. I was overwriting the characteristics references when the 2nd bluetooth chip was connected, so I coudn't write on the first one. I did some maps to hold chip address and its characteristics and now it is working.